# Magento2 : How to force Shipping Address is the same as Billing Address?

Tags: magento2, shipping-address, billing-address, checkout-page

Is there a way to prevent the addition of a different address at checkout, so that billing and shipping addresses are always the same?

With this I'd like to also prevent the user adding a shipping address in their account, and if they already have more than one to hide any but the first. And that updating the billing address also updates the shipping address.

Since I don't believe this is a on/off functionality in the Magento 2 backend I assume this would require and entire module?

Comment: you need to force customer to fill same shipping and billing address, right?

Comment: I'd prefer to remove the shipping information entirely and pass the billing info to the payment gateway as the shipping info.

Comment: you can used magento event obserer functionality to set same shipping address.

Answer (score 0):

Add This code on your header

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        require(['jquery'],function($){


                $(document).ready(function () {
                     $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
                         if($('input#billing-address-same-as-shipping-shared').prop("checked") == true){
                        }else{
                            $('input#billing-address-same-as-shipping-shared').trigger('click');
                        }
                });
            });

        });

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .field._required[name="shippingAddress.city"],.box.box-address-billing { display: none!important; }
        .checkout-billing-address { display: none; }
        /*.checkout-billing-address { pointer-events: none; display: none; }
        input#billing-address-same-as-shipping-shared { opacity: .5; }*/
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this method](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/236444/remove-my-billing-and-shipping-address-are-the-same-in-magento2/),
without the following line:

```html
<render args="detailsTemplate"/>
```

Briefly tested, should work for the frontend.